# Jekyll's erratic date recognition in frontmatter

Tags: ruby, date, yaml, jekyll

I've recently started experimenting with Jekyll (v 3.0.1, using Ruby 2.2.3p173 on Ubuntu), and I'm not sure if I've found a bug or it is a PEBKAC somehow.

I have a couple of articles which I'd like to sort using their "date" value defined in their frontmatter, like this:

```
---
title: Whatever
category: foo
date: 2014-09-7
---
```

I've been using the following Liquid tag to generate the sorted collection:

```
{% assign sorted=site.pages | where: 'category', include.category | sort: 'date' %}
```

It was working fine, but as I was adding articles Jekyll suddenly blew up and presented the following error message:

*"Liquid Exception: Liquid error: comparison of Jekyll::Page with Jekyll::Page failed in (the file name)"*

After a lot of experimenting I wrote a custom plugin, but it still wouldn't work. Inspecting the collection however has revealed that the value of the date attribute sometimes gets magically converted into a date object, but mostly it is a string.

And here comes the part which I can't figure out.

What's so special about "2015-12-10"?

"2015-12-9" is still a string as is "but "2015-15-10" becomes a date object. **Actually, if both the month and the day are 2 digit numbers, Jekyll blows up.**

Interestingly, if I've modified the problematic frontmatter by quoting the date value, it started working as expected:

```
---
title: Whatever 2
category: foo
date: "2015-12-15"
---
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It also happened with my site. I'm very interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How Jekyll sees front matter values ?

```
dates:
  - "2015-12-21" # String
  - 2015-12-21   # Date
  - 2015-12-1    # String
  - 2015-12-01   # Date
  - 2015-12-21 12:21:22  # Time
  - 2015-12-21 12:21:22 +0100 # Time
```

#### Sorting strings

If you sort 'dates' like `date: "yyyy-mm-dd"` mixed with 'date' like `date: "yyyy-mm-d"` this will fail.

```
---
datesAsStrings:
  - "2015-12-1"
  - "2015-12-3"
  - "2015-12-12"
---
{% assign sortedDates = page.datesAsStrings | sort %}
{% for date in sortedDates %}<p>{{ date }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

Returns :

```
2015-12-1
2015-12-12
2015-12-3
```

#### Date sort

If you sort valid dates (`yyyy-mm-dd`), sorting is ok.

```
---
datesAsDates:
  - 2015-12-01
  - 2015-12-03
  - 2015-12-21
---
{% assign sortedDates = page.datesAsDates | sort %}
{% for date in sortedDates %}<p>{{ date }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

returns :

```
2015-12-01
2015-12-03
2015-12-21
```

#### Blowing it up

If you mix Dates (`yyyy-mm-dd`) with Strings (`yyyy-mm-d`)

```
mixed:
  - 2015-12-1
  - 2015-12-03
{% assign sortedDates = page.mixed | sort %}
{% for date in sortedDates %}<p>{{ date }}</p>{% endfor %}

Error: Liquid error: comparison of String with Date failed
```

or with Times (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`)

```
---
datesAsDatesOrTime:
  - 2015-12-01
  - 2015-12-03 12:12:12 +0100
---
{% assign sortedDates = page.datesAsDatesOrTime | sort %}
{% for date in sortedDates %}<p>{{ date }}</p>{% endfor %}

Error: Liquid error: comparison of Date with Time failed
```

This is the same problem you have when sorting page with different date types.

#### Conclusion

- In front matter, a valid **Date** for Jekyll is `mydate: yyyy-mm-dd` and **not** `mydate: "yyyy-mm-dd"` or `mydate: yyyy-mm-d` .
- You can only sort elements of same type.
- You can only sort pages, posts or collections on a variable that has the same type in each of them.

Comment: Thank you David for this thorough explanation.